# How do you do systems work in C++?

Tags: c++, c, system-calls

In my computer science program we've been taught to work with child processes and forks and pipes and file descriptors etc etc in C, but we've never done comparable stuff in C++.

Do you use the same libraries, or does C++ have some (hopefully simplified) systems libraries of its own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The types of things you have described are actually system specific rather then C specific. If you look around you might be able to find some wrappers for them, but they are not part of the C++ standard (nor the C standard).

As an example, there's no reason to use file descriptors in standard C. That's what the file struct, fopen, fclose, fread, fwrite, etc are for. If you're using file descriptors it's because you're being taught about the operating system rather than about C.

Answer (score 0):

Fork, pipe, exec; parent processes, child processes: You are talking about POSIX. The POSIX standard is written in terms of C rather than C++. With a few exceptions, the POSIX library functions are either consistent with the C standard or augment it. You can call C functions from C++, so this same functionality is available on a POSIX-compliant C/C++ system. However, the focus is on C rather than C++ because that's the native language for library functions such as `fork`, the `exec` family of functions, and so on.

C++11 has adopted the threading concept from POSIX and Windows, but the heavy-weight multiprocessing stuff such as fork and exec, pipes, etc.: that's C-based.

Comment: I don't think the language in which POSIX is implemented is any consequence to use in C or C++. There are many who wrongly believe that those function built in C should be used by C client code. A classic example is Win32 with C and MFC with C++.

Comment: Win32C and MFC are proprietary. They are not international standards. POSIX is. The POSIX standard dictates that the programmatic interface to POSIX be written in C, not C++. The POSIX standard levies a number of requirements beyond those of the C standard on the C standard library, and a few on the compiler as well (including at least one where the standards collide.)

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing specific to C or C++ w.r.t processes, child processes, etc. What is available while you program in C should be available for C++. You can always use a wrapper class that can be designed for object oriented style and for the benefits of RAII.

Comment: The C++11 standard adds quite a lot of features that help with multiprocessing and multithreading.

Comment: Here the question is specific to processes. There is nothing to do with processes in C++11 standard and that is what I have written. Also have a good reason to downvote.